# NSURLConnection response's expectedContentLength -1

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection, transfer-encoding

*

> Note: There are several links on this topic but it didn't work for me,
>   So I have to post the new one here.

*

Basically I'm trying to show the UIProgressView to show the data being fetched from the web service. Now problem is that I'm getting the expectedContentLength for almost all the service that I call from my application and the response headers contains the **Content-Length**. But for one of the web service's response it doesn't return the expectedContentLength, instead always returns -1.

Following are the response headers that I get for two different web service response :

*- Response header for which I get the content length.(Data from service is not huge)*

```
{
    Connection = "Keep-Alive";
    "Content-Length" = 2689;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
    Date = "Tue, 23 Jun 2015 08:19:04 GMT";
    "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=5, max=98";
    Server = "Apache/2.4.10 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1i PHP/5.5.15";
    "X-Powered-By" = "PHP/5.5.15";
}
```

*- Response header for which I don't get the content length. (Response contains the huge data, no files to be downloaded just **JSON** data)*

```
{
    Connection = "Keep-Alive";
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
    Date = "Tue, 23 Jun 2015 08:12:34 GMT";
    "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=5, max=97";
    Server = "Apache/2.4.10 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1i PHP/5.5.15";
    "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
    "X-Powered-By" = "PHP/5.5.15";
}
```

The Above service response contains huge data. When tested the response on **Advanced rest client chrome's extension** It gives following response header with  "Transfer-Encoding" = chunked;.

```
Date: Tue, 23 Jun 2015 12:01:20 GMT 
Server: Apache/2.4.10 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1i PHP/5.5.15 
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.15
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked 
Content-Type: application/json
```

I used following links, but none of them helped me:
[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14775628/why-does-my-nsurlconnection-report-an-incorrect-expectedcontentlength) ,  [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417610/why-response-expectedcontentlength-always-return-1?rq=1) ,  [Link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7417610/why-response-expectedcontentlength-always-return-1?lq=1)

Please help me.
Thanks!

**Updated code:**
After setting the Content-Lenth header on server side I got the valid response with Content-Length header on **Advanced rest client chrome's extension**.

```
Date: Wed, 24 Jun 2015 05:25:48 GMT 
Server: Apache/2.4.10 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1i PHP/5.5.15 
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.15
Content-Length: 1272347 
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/json
```

But on client side (i.e in iOS Application) I still didn't get the Content-Lenth header so that I can get the expectedContentLength value.
I still get "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity; in the response header on my side.
I have also set the Accept-Encoding header in the request as follows :

> [req setValue:@"identity;q=0" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Encoding"];

Is there anything more to be done on either side(server/client).

Comment: Try with AFNetworking for parsing web-services. that is very nice class and fast as well. Also i guess you're not setting right content-Type or serialization for response.

Comment: Re: this being tagged as ios, objective-c, etc; do you think the server is specifying a Content-Length that you're somehow losing? If not then the best you can do on the client side is prediction. Also: using some third-party framework isn't going to help.

Comment: @Tommy Content-Length is not being specified manually from the server side. But here I want to rectify whether its just the huge amount of that data I'm fetching from the server that i'm not getting the content-length.

Comment: @Mahesh for me, at least, that doesn't clarify the question. You're just looking for someone to say 'yes' or 'no' to the question 'is it just the huge amount of data I'm fetching from the server that's causing me not to get a content-length'? Or something else. I might be acting like a stupid person.

Comment: The problem is that your server is not setting the value.

Comment: @Tommy Sorry for not being clear enough for you to understand my issue. Issue I'm facing is that when accessing the web service, in response header I'm getting "chunked transfer encoding" and "content-length header" is ignored(May be due to large amount of data). So I'm unable to get the expectedContentLength of the service response. So is there any way by which I can get the Content-Length Header in response so that I can get the expectedContentLenght.

Comment: @DavidH: Can you have look at my updated question? Now we are setting the value for the content-lenght from the server, still I'm not getting Content-Length Header field in the service response on my iOS application. Any help please?

Comment: @Mahesh, were you able to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how one gets the content length added at the server side - I had problems with this before, and in one case I had a similar situation as yours - the content length was visible by dumping all headers, but iOS didn't hand it to me in the delegate method. The standard way to get it is via:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)conn didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
  ...
  NSUInteger responseLength = response.expectedContentLength == NSURLResponseUnknownLength ? 1024 : (NSUInteger)response.expectedContentLength;
```

I actually entered a bug on this: rdar://15605995 "HTTP Get response is 200 but response.expectedContentLength = -1 even when a Content-Length is found in the headers"

```
2014-01-08 18:49:36.966 DB_Lookup[36824:3f07] YIKES:LEN=22162 {
"Cache-Control" = "must-revalidate";
Connection = "keep-alive";
"Content-Encoding" = gzip;
"Content-Length" = 22162;
"Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=UTF-8";
Date = "Wed, 08 Jan 2014 23:49:09 GMT";
Expires = 0;
"Front-End-Https" = on;
Pragma = "no-cache";
Server = "nginx/1.2.4";
"Strict-Transport-Security" = "max-age=2592000";
Vary = "Accept-Encoding";
"X-Content-Type-Options" = nosniff;
"X-Frame-Options" = SAMEORIGIN;
"X-Powered-By" = <Company>;
"X-<Company>-Server" = "<private>";
"X-XSS-Protection" = "1; mode=block";
```

}

for this code:

```
if(response.expectedContentLength == NSURLResponseUnknownLength) { 
    id len = httpResponse.allHeaderFields[@"Content-Length"];
    if(len) {
        responseLength = [len integerValue];
    }
    NSLog(@"YIKES:LEN=%@ %@", len, httpResponse.allHeaderFields);
}
```

This is going to be really hard for me to special case. I'm accessing an internal company data base, I have to use name/password first, then get a code to my phone (which I later enter) to get in. Is there other info I could grab to help you? How can it be that the content length is clearly there in the header, but you don't see it and return it to me?

---

Apple closed my bug, saying "Works as Expected". Really!?!?!?!?!?!?!

[I don't know if NSURLSession fixed it or not.]

EDIT: I should have added that in the past, other sites I connected to DID result in a properly set 'expectedContentLength'.