# NSURLConnection, didReceiveResponse expectedContentLength getting -1

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

I am using a GET for getting a data from Server, Want to implement a progressbar, for that i tried to capture expectedContentLength in the didReceiveResponse delegate method. 
How can it can be solved?

```
NSString* serverUrl = @"https:testURL";

receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength:0];

NSURL* url =[NSURL URLWithString:[serverUrl stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[theRequest setValue:@"identity" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Encoding"];**(I tried it after seeing other solutions over Web)**

[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
```

...

```
- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {

    [receivedData setLength:0];
    expectedBytes = [response expectedContentLength];
}
```

Comment: Not all servers (or more precisely, not all requests) return a `Content-Length` header. It is quite frequent for scripts to omit it. If the server is under your control, make sure it sends an appropriate `Content-Length` header.

Comment: We are not getting Content-Length in the allHeaders

Comment: Some [have reported](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17444913/1271826) that `Accept-encoding` of `gzip;q=0` works. Others [have suggested](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11204338/1271826) a zero length string. I've used `identity` listed in your question successfully.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{
     _contentLength = [response expectedContentLength];

}
-(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data{
 _receiveLength += data.length;
}
```

Do you think so?